# Move entity properties into existing tabs like Node?

Tags: entities, 9

When creating a custom content entity, how can I get the properties to automatically arrange themselves on the form like adding/editing a node does out of the box? I'd like the experience to be consistent if possible. See attached photo.

[image: drupal admin]

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. By "properties" do you mean fields? Do the tabs in your custom entity already exist?

Comment: I don't understand either. What do you mean by 'properties'?

Comment: Certain fields/properties like uid, created, changed, etc are usually arranged without intervention from a user on a node. This isn't happening for custom content entities, because its not implemented in Gin yet. https://www.drupal.org/project/gin/issues/3188521

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its a bug in the Gin admin theme. https://www.drupal.org/project/gin/issues/3188521